# A simple upper bound for the Gamma function of a product

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds

Given integer $p \ge 1$ and $q \in [0,1)$, is there a simple upper bound on the quantity $\Gamma(p(1-q))$, where $\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$ is the gamma function?

Comment: Can $p$ be less than or equal to $0$? As you know, the gamma function has a very different behavior when substituting positive and negative numbers.

Comment: What sort of bound are you after?

Comment: @MH.Lee I've updated this now to include $p\ge 1$.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger If it is possible, I wanted a bound that decouples the dependence, so something of the form $\Gamma(p(1-q)) \le f(p) g(q)$ where $f$ and $g$ are some functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(1-q)\ge 1$, then since $\Gamma$ is increasing on $[2,\infty)$, then the upper bound is $\Gamma(p)=p!$

If $0<p(1-q)<1$, then (from integral by parts) $\Gamma(s+1) = s\Gamma(s)$, so $$\Gamma(p(1-q)) = \frac{1}{p(1-q)}\Gamma(p(1-q)+1)\le \frac{2}{p(1-q)}.$$

So I guess a very rough upper limit is $\displaystyle\max\left\{p!, \frac{2}{p(1-q)}\right\}$, and you can discard the max sign if you know the range of $p(1-q)$.